# How to configure xvfb default installation on Jenkins startup?

Tags: jenkins, docker, xvfb

I am setting up a Jenkins instance in Docker.  I am using /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh to install the plugins.  I am copying groovy scripts to /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/ to initialize some configuration.

I can't figure out how to initialize an Xvfb installation location.  There are classes is the org.jenkinsci.plugins.xvfb namespace.  I am not sure which class to use to setup a default installation that finds the app from the PATH (which should be the default???).

Help?

Comment: I tried to copy a default file into /var/jenkins_home, but jenkins didn't seem to use it.  When I bring up the system configuration, it see it and I can apply the change.  Could I do this and then have a groovy script in init.groovy.d that does Jenkins.instance.reload()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this script in `init.groovy.d` directory:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.xvfb.*

def installation = new XvfbInstallation('default', '/usr/local/bin', null)

Jenkins.getInstance()
       .getDescriptorByType(Xvfb.XvfbBuildWrapperDescriptor.class)
       .setInstallations(installation)
```

The `default` is the name of the Xvfb installation, and `/usr/local/bin` is the directory where Xvfb binary resides, change accordingly.